# create a nested list from a list where where the difference between consecutive elements is less than a particular number

Tags: python, list, arraylist, nested-lists

I have a list like this,

```
 l=[1,5,6,9,14,16,17,20,21,29]
```

Now I want to create all possible list from above list with the condition the distance between consecutive numbers will be less than three.

So, the final list should look like,

```
l=[[1],[5,6],[9],[14,16,17],[20,21],[29]]
```

I could do this using a for loop, but the execution time is high, Is there any way to do it with minimum execution time.

Comment: Show us your try [mre] and we might be able to help you fix bugs. What means "execution time is high"? what is "minimum execution time"? using a for loop should be O(n) - you need to check/touch each element of your list so it wont get much faster then that.

Comment: How is the execution time high? doing it using a for loop would have linear complexity

Answer (score 0):

The fastest you can do this is O(n) - we need to individually look at every element once. The for loop below does this.

```
def consecutive_difference(lst, n):
    rv = []
    consec_list = [l[0]]
    for x in lst[1:]:
        if x - consec_list[-1] >= n:
            rv.append(consec_list)
            consec_list = [x]
        else:
            consec_list.append(x)
    rv.append(consec_list)
    return rv
```

**Output**

```
>>> consecutive_difference(l, 3)
[[1], [5, 6], [9], [14, 16, 17], [20, 21], [29]]
```